# How to parse the json values from controller to view in jquery/ ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am using CodeIgniter, In that I need to parse the json string from controller

Here is my code:

```
   public function autosuggest_country(){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT country, count(country) as `Total` FROM list GROUP BY country");

        //echo"<pre>"; print_r($query->result()); 
        echo json_encode($query->result());     }
```

And Getting output as

```
[{"country":"Colombia","Total":"1"},{"country":"Estonia","Total":"1"},{"country":"India","Total":"13"},{"country":"Mexico","Total":"1"},{"country":"USA","Total":"1"}]
```

And I don't know how to parse this json type output into $.getJSON() data parameter?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: its already a json object. you don't need to parse it again.

Answer (score 2):

Please read about **getJSON()** method carefully from jQuery api page.

There all are described how to process your json data as per your requirements..

**getJSON()** is shorthand of Ajax Function which is equivalent to

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success
});
```

So you can easily access the json data which is described in the following url..

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: oh yeah jquery api porvide all solutions about its methods or library

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
var obj = '[{"country":"Colombia","Total":"1"},{"country":"Estonia","Total":"1"},{"country":"India","Total":"13"},{"country":"Mexico","Total":"1"},{"country":"USA","Total":"1"}]'
```

You can use `JSON.parse(obj);`, its plain/vanila javascript. [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/G37G4/).

More about **[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**

If you are using [**jQuery ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you can set the dataType to json:

> **"json":** Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

This is how a standard ajax code can look like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "yourfile.php",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data, text){
     //here is your object "data"
  }
});
```

Comment: this obj value executing from the query, and I am asking how can i parse this query value in the ajax

Comment: `jQuery.ajax()` parses the JSON object automatically if you set `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: @user2451266, you mean you want to know how to make a ajax() call to receive that encoded json?

Comment: @Sergio yes, How to make a ajax call to receive that encoded json

Comment: @Sergio, Thanks for the Update. In Success data results as the object.I Need to fetch country value alone and then append the total value of each country with the results  in the auto complete

Comment: @user2451266, you can make a loop (.each() or a good old for loop) and retrieve that. Something like http://jsfiddle.net/Vq5D2/